# Hyperfactorial curiosity

Tags: notation, special-functions, gamma-function

I've been familiarizing myself with the hyperfactorial, and I'm simply curious if it has an extension/analogue into the world of rational numbers, irrational numbers, and complex numbers like the common factorial has with the Gamma Function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose I should write something slightly more elaborate than the previous answer.

There is a chain of relations connecting the gamma function, the hyperfactorial $H(n)$, and the [Barnes G function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BarnesG-Function.html) (double gamma function) $G(n)$:

$$H(n)=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)^n}{G(n+1)}$$

where $G(n)$ satisfies the functional equation $G(n+1)=\Gamma(n)G(n)$.

Now, the Barnes function has [a number of expressions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.17) that are valid for arbitrary complex argument; for instance,

$$G(z+1)=(2\pi)^{z/2}\exp\left(-\frac{z(z+1)}{2}-\frac{\gamma z^2}{2}\right)\prod_{k=1}^\infty\left(\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)^k\exp\left(-z+\frac{z^{2}}{2k}\right)\right)$$

Combine this with the [usual product formula](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.8.E2) for $\Gamma$ to obtain an infinite product representation for $H$.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the [Hyperfactorial given at MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperfactorial.html), then yes. That page has details, though I don't want to make any quotes, since I'm not familiar enough with the area to make judgement calls about where to start/end a quote.